# How to encapsulated javascript code using imutable method?

Tags: javascript, react.js, typescript

I have this code, but I need to return pure functions instead the mutating functions.

Is it possible? Perhaps using OOP? I don't know how to improve it.

I tried to return the values in each function, but I haven't had success.

```
import { AssetStatusType } from '@domain/interfaces/common'

import {
  BothComponentType,
  ComponentsType,
  GroupFiltersType,
  OperationType,
  OverviewModelType,
  PendenciesOverviewType,
  PendenciesType,
  StructurePendenciesCount,
  StructureStatusCount
} from '../../types'

const updateStatusCount = (
  statusCount: StructureStatusCount,
  status: AssetStatusType
) => {
  statusCount[status] = (statusCount[status] || 0) + 1
}

const updatePendenciesCount = (
  pendenciesCount: StructurePendenciesCount,
  key: AssetStatusType,
  subKey: OperationType | PendenciesOverviewType
) => {
  pendenciesCount[key] = pendenciesCount[key] ?? {}
  pendenciesCount[key][subKey] = (pendenciesCount[key]?.[subKey] || 0) + 1
}

const processOverviewPendencies = (
  pendencies: PendenciesType[] | null | undefined,
  pendenciesCount: StructurePendenciesCount,
  countedIds: Set<string>,
  id: string
) => {
  if (pendencies?.length) {
    for (const { state, pendencyType } of pendencies) {
      const uniqueId = `${state}-${pendencyType}-${id}`
      if (!countedIds.has(uniqueId)) {
        updatePendenciesCount(pendenciesCount, state, pendencyType)

        countedIds.add(uniqueId)
      }
    }
  }
}

const processOverviewComponents = (
  components: ComponentsType[],
  isGroupByTree: boolean,
  statusCount: StructureStatusCount,
  pendenciesCount: StructurePendenciesCount,
  countedIds: Set<string>,
  id: string,
  type: BothComponentType
) => {
  for (const { pendencies, status, operationType } of components) {
    if (isGroupByTree && type === 'location') {
      updateStatusCount(statusCount, status)

      if (operationType) {
        updatePendenciesCount(pendenciesCount, status, operationType)
      }
    }
    processOverviewPendencies(pendencies, pendenciesCount, countedIds, id)
  }
}

const processOverviewData = (
  data: OverviewModelType[],
  groupBy: GroupFiltersType,
  statusCount: StructureStatusCount,
  pendenciesCount: StructurePendenciesCount,
  countedIds: Set<string>
) => {
  const isGroupByTree = groupBy === 'tree'
  const isGroupByAsset = groupBy === 'asset'

  for (const { id, status, components, operationType, type } of data) {
    if (isGroupByAsset || type === 'asset') {
      updateStatusCount(statusCount, status)
      if (operationType) {
        updatePendenciesCount(pendenciesCount, status, operationType)
      }
    }

    processOverviewComponents(
      components,
      isGroupByTree,
      statusCount,
      pendenciesCount,
      countedIds,
      id,
      type
    )
  }
}

export const calculateOverviewCounts = (
  data: OverviewModelType[],
  groupBy: GroupFiltersType
) => {
  const statusCount: StructureStatusCount = {} as StructureStatusCount
  const pendenciesCount: StructurePendenciesCount =
    {} as StructurePendenciesCount

  const countedIds = new Set<string>()

  processOverviewData(data, groupBy, statusCount, pendenciesCount, countedIds)

  return { ...statusCount, pendencies: pendenciesCount }
}
```

Is there a cleaner and more elegant way to do this? I need to return an object like this:

```
// calculateOverviewCounts return this

{
    pendencies: StructurePendenciesCount;
    working: number;
    inAlert: number;
    warning: number;
    stopped: number;
    off: number;
}
```

StructurePendenciesCount is:
[image: StructurePendenciesCount]

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Please [edit] your question so that the title describes the *purpose* of the code, rather than its *mechanism*.  We really need to understand the motivational context to give good reviews. Please see [_How to get the best value out of Code Review: Asking Questions_](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really understand what the code is trying to do, but I can comment in general.

When you have a tree structure like this, you can usually flatten it to make the problem much easier to solve. Some tips:

- Use `Array.flatMap` to un-nest the tree.
- Use lodash `uniqBy` (or write your own) on the flattened tree to get unique pendency items before counting them
- Use lodash `countBy` (or write your own) to count by status
- Replace `if (pendencies?.length)` with `pendencies ?? []` to reduce branching (and shouldn't it be "dependencies"?)
- Try to answer each question with a different function (as opposed to answering all questions within one iteration of the tree structure). If performance is a concern (doubtful), you may ignore this
- Fix the data structure, if that's possible. Name things the same (state vs status). groupBy asset is on a type of asset, but groupBy tree is on a location. Seems a bit odd. Status in general seems like it could be in a separate, attached object instead of inlined in each model.

For example, to get status counts (all code is untested. The filters seem wrong):

```
const components = overviews.flatMap(overview => overview.components)
const assetOverviews = overviews.filter(overview => groupBy === 'asset' && overview.type === 'asset')
const treeComponents = components.filter(component => groupBy === 'tree' && component.type === 'location')
const statusCounts = _.countBy([...assetOverviews,...treeComponents], x => x.status)
```

Similarly for pendencies:

```
const uniquePendencies = _(overviews)
    .flatMap(overview => overview.components.map(component => ({ component, overview })))
    .flatMap(({ overview, component }) => (component.pendencies ?? []).map(pendency => ({ overview, pendency })))
    .uniqBy(({ overview, pendency }) => `${pendency.state}-${pendency.pendencyType}-${overview.id}`)
    .map(x => x.pendency)
    .value()
```

You can then map to a common structure for all your arrays:

```
const pendencyCountItems = [
    ...overviews.filter(o => o.operationType).map(o => ({ key: o.status, subKey: o.operationType })),
    ...components.filter(o => o.operationType).map(o => ({ key: o.status, subKey: o.operationType })),
    ...uniquePendencies.map(o => ({ key: o.state, subKey: o.pendencyType })),
]
```

Which you can then group and count:

```
const pendencyCounts = _(pendencyCountItems)
    .groupBy('key')
    .mapValues(itemsThisStatus => _.countBy(itemsThisStatus, 'subType'))
    .value()
```